# Echo JSON value

Tags: php, json

I have called one webservice using the below code. Now I want to echo some value from it. But I am not able to . I tried some option but they didnt worked.

```
 <?php
    $api_url = "myurl";
    $response = file_get_contents($api_url);
    $my_array = json_decode($response, true);    
?>
```

the above code gives me JSON resonse

```js
{
    "places":{
        "place":[
            {
                "place_id":"FHa5VXVTU7MbX9qW",
                "woeid":"2192348",
                "latitude":"32.433",
                "longitude":"74.366",
                "place_url":"\/Pakistan\/Punjab\/Bhopalwala",
                "place_type":"locality",
                "place_type_id":"7",
                "timezone":"Asia\/Karachi",
                "name":"Bhopalwala, Punjab, Pakistan",
                "woe_name":"Bhopalwala"
            }
        ],
        "latitude":"32.45",
        "longitude":"74.34",
        "accuracy":"16",
        "total":1
    },
    "stat":"ok"
}
```

I tried to echo woe_name.

```
echo $my_array['places']['place']['woe_name'];
print $my_array->places["0"]->place->woe_name;
```

Here is var_dump

```
array(2) {
  ["places"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["place"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(10) {
        ["place_id"]=>
        string(16) "FHa5VXVTU7MbX9qW"
        ["woeid"]=>
        string(7) "2192348"
        ["latitude"]=>
        string(6) "32.433"
        ["longitude"]=>
        string(6) "74.366"
        ["place_url"]=>
        string(27) "/Pakistan/Punjab/Bhopalwala"
        ["place_type"]=>
        string(8) "locality"
        ["place_type_id"]=>
        string(1) "7"
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(12) "Asia/Karachi"
        ["name"]=>
        string(28) "Bhopalwala, Punjab, Pakistan"
        ["woe_name"]=>
        string(10) "Bhopalwala"
      }
    }
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(5) "32.45"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(5) "74.34"
    ["accuracy"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["total"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["stat"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: did you try a var_dump or print_r to see what you would get?

Comment: The JSON you posted doesn't appear to be valid

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem or not, but that doesn't look like valid JSON to me. http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$my_array = json_decode($response);
$my_array->places->place[0]->woe_name;
```

`my_array` contains an object, `places` contains an object, `place` contains an array with a nested object.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```php
echo $my_array['places']['place'][0]['woe_name'];
```

If the second parameter of [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is `true` it will return an array. You can use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.var-dump.php) to check a varables type if you're not sure.

In Json, curly braces `{}` are used for objects with `"key": value` pairs, square braces `[]` are used for arrays of objects.

Answer (score 1):

It misses a `{` in the beginning of your json.

With it, it gives:

```
$my_array['places']['place'][0]['woe_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your JSON is missing a curly brackey - you need to create one at the beginning, it's missing a

'{' before "places"